# composer update out of memory no matter what I do

Tags: macos, composer-php

I've gone through a bunch of website recommendations and StackOverflow answers and comments to try to figure this out, I'm at a loss now. I'm using a MacBook Pro 2019 with macOS Big Sur (latest), 16GB of RAM, using MAMP Pro with PHP 5.6 or 7.3 (compatible with the repo). The repo last had its composer updated last year.

```
Me@My-MacBook-Pro the-repo % composer update --verbose
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///Applications/MAMP/bin/php/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 204
```

This happens when trying with PHP 5.6 or 7.3, which the repo and my MAMP Pro is compatible with. I use MAMP Pro because it's been the only way I could get these multi-version repos working on my Mac (which started at Catalina, and Homebrew stopped supporting old libraries, and trying to find and compile the correct libraries for PHP 5 on Mac has been a nightmare).

The repo is run on MAMP PRo Apache, PHP 5.6 or 7.3 as CGI, and with the default version set to activate CLI commands with that PHP version. Composer runs the PHP version specified there as far as I can tell. Running `php -v` shows the expected version either way.

```
% composer --version
Composer version 2.1.14 2021-11-30 10:51:43
% composer self-update
You are already using the latest available Composer version 2.1.14 (stable channel).
```

I tried checking https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors, as suggested. Trying those suggestions doesn't help. I upped MAMP Pro's php.ini memory to 4G for both PHP versions. Running `printenv` shows no COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT var.

```
% php -d memory_limit=-1 `which composer` update
Could not open input file: composer:
```

I moved the `vendor` folder outside of the repo. Same thing. I'm at a complete loss of how to run `composer update` on this repo. Adding `--verbose` to the command showed no detailed information, I can't even tell which package it fails on.

Comment: Have you tried using more specific version constraints? In the past, I've seen such problems when the version constraints are so loose that the dependency resolve had to check too many possible combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the problem was caused by me having MB or GB in php.ini instead of just M after the number... so I guess I forgot that bit of unintuitive formatting that PHP has for its memory limit. Silly me.